# Customer login event not working

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, logging

I want to redirect to home on customer login and i don't want to work this redirection on checkout login
here is my code
/app/etc/modules/Cusredirection_customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cusredirection_customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Cusredirection_customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Cusredirection/customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cusredirection_customer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Cusredirection_customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cusredirection_customer>
                <class>Cusredirection_customer_Model</class>
            </cusredirection_customer>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
              <observers>
                  <cusredirection_customer>
                      <class>cusredirection_customer/observer</class>
                      <method>customerLogin</method>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                  </cusredirection_customer>
              </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Cusredirection/customer/Model/observer.php

```
<?php
class Cusredirection_customer_Model_Observer
{
    public function setRedirectOnLogin(){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false)
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());  
        else             
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());

        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your folder name `customer` should be `Customer`

change as per this

here is my code /app/etc/modules/Cusredirection_Customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cusredirection_Customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Cusredirection_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Cusredirection/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cusredirection_Customer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Cusredirection_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cusredirection_customer>
                <class>Cusredirection_Customer_Model</class>
            </cusredirection_customer>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
              <observers>
                  <cusredirection_customer>
                      <class>cusredirection_customer/observer</class>
                      <method>setRedirectOnLogin</method>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                  </cusredirection_customer>
              </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Cusredirection/Customer/Model/observer.php

```
<?php
class Cusredirection_Customer_Model_Observer
{
    public function setRedirectOnLogin(){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false)
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());  
        else             
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());

        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have changed as per your suggestion but the problem is still there . While login as customer it going to account page

Comment: @Amith check updated code in `config.xml`

Comment: No change still it going to customer/account/index/ page

Comment: @ Murtuza Is there any other way to do this using any other event?